# Ember issue: Uncaught Error: Could not find module handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Let's learn Ember.js</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"</script>
        <script src="handlebars-1.1.2.js"</script>
        <script src="ember-1.5.1.js"</script>
        <script>
            window.App = Ember.Application.create();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
            <h1>Welcome to Ember.js!</h1>
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**jquery, handlbars and ember** are in the same folder as **index.html**.

When I opened index.html in the Chrome (the address line of the browser looks: file:///home/askar/work/ember/emberjs/index.html ), In the Console tab of Inspect Element I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module handlebars ember-1.5.1.js:251
requireModule ember-1.5.1.js:251
(anonymous function) ember-1.5.1.js:27031
(anonymous function) ember-1.5.1.js:27317
(anonymous function) ember-1.5.1.js:44267
```

What am I doing wrong?

Couldn't find any related posts.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your script tags are missing the closing angle brackets.

Try this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="ember-1.5.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shame on me! :) That was trivial. Thanks a lot!